# Rs485 A & B Labels being used inconsistently

Tags: communication, rs485, protocol, standard, modbus

I would like to know if there is an official standard with regards to rs-485 terminals being labelled **A** & **B**.

I have always believed:
**A**=> + (positive)
and
**B**=> - (negative)

however, I have recently worked on WEG and Danfos VSD and they seem to have **A(-)** Negative & **B(+)** positive.

Is there an official standard or is this miss-used around the world depending on each product and or brand?

Answer (score 5):

RS-485 standard defines the A line as negative and B line as positive, as can be seen from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485#Signals):

> The RS-485 differential line consists of two signals:
>
> - A, which is low for logic 1 and high for logic 0 and,
> - B, which is high for logic 1 and low for logic 0.

Manufacturers often don't follow this convention and label the lines reversed: A for positive, B for negative. Some of them even use a different convention such as D+ and D-.

It's always good to check the manual of the equipment.

Answer (score 3):

The TIA-485 standard states:

> The A terminal of the generator shall be negative with respect to the B terminal for a binary 1 (OFF) state

and

> The A terminal of the generator shall be positive with respect to the B terminal for a binary 0 (ON) state

That's it. A+ or A- or any other label is not described in the standard. The interpretation of the above is not obvious (Atleast i find in conflicting; binary 0 is *on?*) so that is probably the reason that most transceiver manufacturers has landed on a terminology that one might argue contradicts the standard.

While we are on it though; the standard does not:

- Define the actual logic operation of the transceivers.
- Define any network biasing I.e: What is the "correct" idle voltage on
  the bus?
- It only mentions failsafe, but avoids the topic of implementation as
  that is "application specific" (As a result every single transceiver
  manufacturer has come up with their own ideas - that may or may not
  be compatible to each-other) (It is better these days though. Modern
  transceivers are pretty darn good, but ~15 years ago that was painful. And: some of that nonsense still lingers behind as bad practices)

However; How anyone is able to make functioning R485 network based on a standard that barely covers the essentials is a mystery to me. (Fun fact; They don't. Ever tried to build a network with devices from different vendors? It is a nightmare.) I've seen plenty of crazy stuff, based on some ideas from a clever engineer reinventing a wheel. It's might be clever, and it might work, but change out the USB converter and the entire network collapses. RS485 can be great but the standard is too vague in it's implementation to ensure compatibility. But: If you control all nodes on the network RS485 can be pretty darn good.

Finally one might hope that the implementation guide TSB-89 might clarify this terminology... but no. But it does offer some more insight in the implementation that i suspect has ether been neglected or ignored by some big brands building RS485 devices.

Comment: This is crazy, I always assumed that because Modbus has been around for so long, and was so widely adopted by so many different devices that it would have a very good and clear standard of implementations. This explains a lot of the issues we have in our day to day jobs.  We integrate different vendors on rs485 networks for remote monitoring.

Answer (score 2):

The following is from the 1994 version of TIA-EIA-422-B, which defines the various parameters for RS-422.

[image]

Note that a 1==mark => Va<Vb.

While I don't have the defining document for RS-485, I would think that, since RS-485 was derived from '422, the official definitions for Va and Vb would be the same.

Now whether all manufacturers of RS-485 devices follow that standard is anyone's guess.

**Added Counterexample below**

And then, after poking around in my files, I came across the datasheet for the National Semiconductor DS26LV31T RS-422 driver.  This data sheet shows that the DO+ output follows the input, while the DO- output is inverted from the input.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an official standard or is this miss-used around the world
> depending on each product and or brand?

No. Different manufacturers may have different labeling. But not just labeling, also the bias resistors may be reversed. For example, take the Siemens Profibus, and you'll notice that it won't match the usual RS485 schematics.

Comment: "No." is not correct, because there *is* an official standard. The problem is that it's not followed consistently.

Comment: @brhans It's not quite that simple.  A- or B+ is never mentioned.

Comment: @Arcatus - according to Rohat's answer (and my own experience), the standard *does* specify that A is 'negative logic' and B is 'positive logic'.